# Keycloak Missing form parameter: grant_type

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak

I have keycloak standalone running on my local machine.

I created new realm called 'spring-test', then new client called 'login-app'

According to the rest documentation:

```
POST: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/spring-test/protocol/openid-connect/token

{
    "client_id": "login-app",
    "username": "user123",
    "password": "pass123",
    "grant_type": "password"
}
```

should give me the jwt token but I get bad request with response

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing form parameter: grant_type"
}
```

I am assuming that something is missing in my configuration.

EDIT:
I was using json body but it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:
the following body works:

```
token_type_hint:access_token&token:{token}&client_id:{client_id}&client_secret:{client_secret}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You should send your data in a POST request with `Content-Type` header value set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not json.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue, even if i set the content type to be urlencoded:
   curl -d '{"grant_type": "password", "username": "user", "password": "pass", "client_id": "login-app"}' -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST "http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/ina-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token"
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing form parameter: grant_type"}

Comment: because you send json data, you should use -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" syntaxis

Comment: This is not working. How do you set that `-d` stuff in postman, @ipave?

Comment: @Avión  here is a link - https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/#urlencoded

Comment: Thanks, I was sending "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------616846104444017186133807"

Answer (score 22):

For those who landed here from a search looking for `JavaScript` solution.

Here is an example when exchanging `code` for `access_token` with `keycloak` authority using `axios`.

Sending the request:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({

    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: 'client-id-here',
    code: 'code-from-previous-redirect',
    redirect_uri: location.protocol + '//' + location.host

});

axios({

    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://my-keycloak.authority/token',
    data: params.toString(),
    config: {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }

}).then(response => {

    console.log(response.data);

}).catch(error => {

    console.error(error);

});
```

> You are required to send a POST request with the parameters as a URL encoded string in the request body.
>
> FormData object does not work.

Comment: There is an easy way to get token without using query string.                                        const config = {
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
};
const formParameter = `client_id=KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=KEYCLOAK_API_GRANT_TYPE`;
 axios.post(REQUEST_URL,formParameter,config);

Comment: [Pavan J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9616168) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67157213) saying "Thanks @marc for the solution and it works! I have been looking for this solution in quite a number of forums. PS: There's a typo in grant_type: 'authorization_code', (closing quote missing)"

Comment: querystring is depricated now 
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v17.0.0/lib/querystring.js

Comment: Since querystring is depricated as @sudarshan pointed out, we can use URLSearchParams instead.  In this code snippet we can substitute 
`new URLSearchParams(params)` for  `queryString.stringify(params)`.  URLSearchParams should be supported in newer versions of node and the browser.  If your version of node doesn't have support for it we can use a polyfill

Answer (score 22):

With Curl

```
curl -X POST \
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/api-gateway/protocol/openid-connect/token \
-H 'Accept: */*' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Content-Length: 73' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=F8CD240FF046572F864DC37148E51128.a139df207ece;   JSESSIONID=65D31B82F8C5FCAA5B1577DA03B4647C' \
-H 'Host: localhost:8080' \
-H 'Postman-Token: debc4f90-f555-4769-b392-c1130726a027,d5087d9f-9253-48bd-bb71-fda1d4558e4d' \
-H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-d 'grant_type=password&client_id=api-gateway&username=admin&password=temp123'
```

By Postman
(Select x-www-form-urlencoded option for parameters)

[image]

Comment: don't forget to put `client_secret`

Answer (score 16):

For those having problems with curl the curl command is as follows

```
curl -d "client_secret=<client-secret>" -d "client_id=<client-id>" -d "username=<username>" -d "password=<password>" -d "grant_type=password" "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

The curl command works without the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample CURL command

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/your_realm_name/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 69' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Cookie: KC_RESTART=' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:8080' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 88f38aa0-8659-4b37-a2aa-d6b92177bdc2,29c4e7db-51f4-48d1-b6d5-daab06b68ab4' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'client_id=my-app&username=admin&password=admin123&grant_type=password'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in SOAPUI testing. We should not POST a json. This got resolved when I cleared 'Media Type' and checked 'PostQueryString' checkbox. 'Media Type box' will set to 'www-form-urlencoded' by itself. Add attributes at Top by hitting plus sign.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ERROR TYPE:
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "Missing form parameter: grant_type"
}

Hi all, if you are experiencing an error in ARC "grant_type" when making a POST request to test keycloak you can do the following modifications in the parameter: set HEADER to "content_type" and set the value to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: Similar answer is already present:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53795226/4081901

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the solution provided [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53795226/3827877)

The below code is directly in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format

```
`grant_type=${encodeURIComponent('authorization_code')}&code=${encodeURIComponent(this.authorizationCode)}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}&client_id=${encodeURIComponent(clientId)}&code_verifier=${encodeURIComponent(codeVerifier)}`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this problem - double check if your client and user belong to the realm in post request.

Answer (score 0):

after changing `Content-Type` from `json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

you must convert json body as [follows](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/java-keycloak-missing-form-parameter-grant_type/)

```
token_type_hint:access_token&token:{token}&client_id:{client_id}&client_secret:{client_secret}
```

see this example:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive

grant_type=password&client_id=springDemo&username=user01&password=user01&client_secret=greJdi4wZCxHsu4AF7HRlLKRwvX8AQBU
```