# Java 11 HttpClient - Missing form parameter: grant_type

Tags: passwords, httpclient, keycloak, java-11

I'm trying to get an access token from Keycloack server via HttpClient of Java 11. But I keep getting an error:

```java
{
    "error":"invalid_request",
    "error_description":"Missing form parameter: grant_type"
}
```

By the way, with postman, I can get the token. What I'm doing in my code is:

```java
        Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>() {{
            put("username", username);
            put ("password", password);
            put("grant_type", "password");
        }};

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String requestBody = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(values);

        HttpRequest request=HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(tokenEndpoint))
                .setHeader("client_id", clientId)
                .setHeader("client_secret", clientSecret)
                .setHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody))
                .build();



        HttpClient.newHttpClient()
                .sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .thenAccept(System.out::println);

        /*
        //Tried also
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(response.body());
        */
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

[Keycloak Missing form parameter: grant_type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795179/keycloak-missing-form-parameter-grant-type) not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we done login:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
requestParams.add("client_id", keycloakProperties.getResource());
requestParams.add("username", username);
requestParams.add("password", password);
requestParams.add("grant_type", "password");
requestParams.add("client_secret", String.valueOf(keycloakProperties.getCredentials().get("secret")));
requestParams.add("scope", "openid");

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestParams, headers);

String url = keycloakProperties.getAuthServerUrl() + "/realms/" + keycloakProperties.getRealm() + "/protocol/openid-connect/token";

AccessTokenResponse keycloakAccessToken = getAccessTokenResponse(request, url);


// sometimes SSL handshake was failing, so catching error and trying again :)
private AccessTokenResponse getAccessTokenResponse(HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request, String url) {
    try {
        ResponseEntity<AccessTokenResponse> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, AccessTokenResponse.class);
        return response.getBody();
    } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
        log.error("KeyCloak getAccessTokenResponse: " + e.getMessage());
        try {
            ResponseEntity<AccessTokenResponse> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, AccessTokenResponse.class);
            return response.getBody();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm accepting your solution as it worked. But I want to understand why did not work my code? There is nothing complex in my code. I tried by adding the grant_type to the header, to the body, to both of them, without it, nothing worked, the error is the same. I don't understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the line `.setHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`, the request is expecting form data,
but you are sending json in the request body (via `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString()`).

If you are trying to send form data, then this should be the correct encoding:

```java
String requestBody = "username=" + username + "password=" + password + "grant_type=password"
```

If the API is expecting JSON, then change the content type header to `application/json`:

```java
HttpRequest request=HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    ...
    .setHeader("content-type", "application/json")
    ...
```

Comment: In TypeScript, `new URLSearchParams({
    code,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    redirect_uri,
  }).toString()` was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem recently, a was using a Map to pass the parameters, and with Map I was getting 'missing grant_type error', when I changed the parameter's type to MultiValueMap, it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).